# In Laravel 5.4 MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail is working on one hosting but not on another hosting

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4

I have devoped a laravel 5.4 website on my hosting (purchased from namecheap.com) successfuly. All emails and contact forms were working successfuly on my hosting. and when I delivered website and hosted on client's hosting, every thing is working as it should, but emails (via contact form) is not working. Even it do not show any error and mail is not sent too. when i change `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail` to `MAIL_DRIVER=log` it send mail in log file `storage/logs/laravel.log`.
any body please help me to solve this problem. I don't that what the problem is being faced.

Comment: Be sure to check the mail log files of the server.

Comment: where the mail log files exist on server..??

Comment: Depends on your server and configuration, but most likely in `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: `in /var/` only there is a directory with the name of `cpanel`. any other directory in idea..??

Comment: if contact forms are not working then project is useless.

Comment: Are sure the server has `sendmail` installed? `locate sendmail` [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail) may help.